# Connecting to MongoDB Atlas using Golang mgo: Persistent no reachable server to replica set

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, replicaset

I have a replica set from MongoDB atlas, to which I can connect with ANY other language, and regular mongo client, with the URL provided with the format :

`mongodb://user:pass@prefix1.mongodb.net:27017,prefix2.mongodb.net:27017,prefix3.mongodb.net:27017/test?&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin`

No matter what I tried, adding `ssl=true` and removing, nothing works. It is always **"no reachable server"**.

I tried every single combination for URL, every combination for dialConfig, and also Dial and DialWithConfig configurations.

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 20):

Using MongoDB Go driver [mgo](https://labix.org/mgo) code snippet below to connect to [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) works, using your example data:

```
import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "crypto/tls"
    "net"
)

tlsConfig := &tls.Config{}

dialInfo := &mgo.DialInfo{
    Addrs: []string{"prefix1.mongodb.net:27017", 
                    "prefix2.mongodb.net:27017",
                    "prefix3.mongodb.net:27017"},
    Database: "authDatabaseName",
    Username: "user",
    Password: "pass",
}
dialInfo.DialServer = func(addr *mgo.ServerAddr) (net.Conn, error) {
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", addr.String(), tlsConfig)
    return conn, err
}
session, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(dialInfo)
```

Note that you can also specify only one of the replica set members as a seed. For example:

```
Addrs: []string{"prefix2.mongodb.net:27017"}
```

See also:

- [tls.Dial()](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Dial)
- [DialInfo](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#DialInfo)
- [DialWithInfo](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#DialWithInfo)

**Update**:

You could also use [ParseURL()](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#ParseURL) method to parse MongoDB Atlas URI string. However, currently this method does not support SSL ([mgo.V2 PR:304](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/pull/304))

A work around is to take out the `ssl=true` line before parsing.

```
//URI without ssl=true
var mongoURI = "mongodb://username:password@prefix1.mongodb.net,prefix2.mongodb.net,prefix3.mongodb.net/dbName?replicaSet=replName&authSource=admin"

dialInfo, err := mgo.ParseURL(mongoURI)

//Below part is similar to above. 
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{}
dialInfo.DialServer = func(addr *mgo.ServerAddr) (net.Conn, error) {
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", addr.String(), tlsConfig)
    return conn, err
}
session, _ := mgo.DialWithInfo(dialInfo)
```

Comment: Would you be able to advise on how the connection string would look if `dialInfo` was generated via this way instead? `dialInfo, err := mgo.ParseURL(url)`. Appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Wan Bachtiar, any idea in how to parse the new URLS for Atlas in Mongo 3.6. Eg. "mongodb+srv://kay:myRealPassword@cluster0.mongodb.net/?serverSelectionTryOnce=false&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=15000"

Comment: @rsan the new official mongo-go-driver should support that. If you’re still having an issue please open a new question and link it here. Please provide the go driver and version that you’re using. Cheers

Comment: @WanBachtiar thanks Wan, Tested and working using the official driver.

Comment: just small update set ```Source``` in ```DialInfo``` else you can get following error 
```panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x1455022]```

I have set ```source: "admin"``` which works fine to me.