# Go and MongoDB connection won't work with panic log "no reachable server"

Tags: bash, mongodb, go, mgo

I am using mGo as a driver for my Go Web App to another MongoDB system. So I am not running Mongo on the same system. (URL is not localhost).

However, I get "panic: no reachable servers" error.

Here is the test function that runs right when the Go server starts:

```
dialInfo, err0 := mgo.ParseURL("mongodb://1234MY456IP:27017,27018")
if err0 != nil {
    panic(err0)
}
dialInfo.Direct = true
dialInfo.FailFast = true
session, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(dialInfo)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer session.Close()
```

One of the answers in a similar question was to make sure MongoDB is running on `netstat` or `ps`.

I don't see any processes running on ps except ps and bash. And I don't see it on netstat either.

That being I've ran sudo service mongod start/stop/restart and tested with the mongo shell. What am I doing wrong?

Err0 and err print the same error message.

Comment: try checking the error returned from mgo.ParseURL, this example is ignoring any error that may be returned.   Also, try to `telnet IP:PORT` to make sure you can connect to the target host/port

Comment: updated the code and same error is returned. telnet just stalls. My AWS settings have the port open, not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the URI should follow the [mgo](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2) URI format

```
[mongodb://][user:pass@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...][/database][?options]
```

See [mgo.v2 Dial func](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Dial) for more information.

If you're connecting to MongoDB Atlas (or your servers require SSL) see also [Connecting to MongoDB Atlas using mgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173720)

Second, make sure you can reach the MongoDB server(s) from your application server. You can utilise [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) to test the connection (eliminating your code issue for now).

Comment: I fixed this a while ago but that must have been the issue: having a bad mgo URI format. thanks for answering!