# How to use new URL from mongodb 3.6 to connect from golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, mongodb-atlas

I tried to connect to mongodb Atlas using golang drivers.

```
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{}

var mongoURI = "mongodb+srv://admin:password@prefix.mongodb.net:27017/dbname"
dialInfo, err := mgo.ParseURL(mongoURI)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
dialInfo.DialServer = func(addr *mgo.ServerAddr) (net.Conn, error) {
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", addr.String(), tlsConfig)
    return conn, err
}

session, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(dialInfo)
if err != nil {
    println("error")
    log.Fatal(err)
}
_ = session
c := session.DB("Token").C("_Users")
user := &User{firstName: "username"}
err = c.Insert(user)
if err != nil {
    println("error Again")
}
```

I am not getting an error not getting connected.
I am wondering what could be the reason.'
Any help is appreciated.

I tried to create DialInfo using below code

```
    dialInfo := &mgo.DialInfo{
    Addrs:     []string{"prefix.mongodb.net:27017"},
    Database:  "dbname",
    Mechanism: "SCRAM",
    Timeout:   10 * time.Second,
    Username:  "admin",
    Password:  "passwrd",
}
```

Now I am getting no reachable servers

Comment: _"I am not getting an error not getting connected."_ This is contradictory. If you can't connect, the `c.Insert()` operation would surely return an error. If you truly don't get any errors, then my guess is that you connect just fine, you insert just fine, but when you want to verify, you're looking in the wrong db/collection?

Comment: I could only see that the code started, then nothing.. My assumption is it is not getting connection itself. What i need to know is that if mgo supports new connection string

Answer (score 4):

> I could only see that the code started, then nothing

As you have figured out, this is because [DialInfo](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#DialInfo) by default has a zero timeout. The call will block forever waiting for a connection to be established. You can also specify a timeout with:

```
dialInfo.Timeout = time.Duration(30)
session, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(dialInfo)
```

> Now I am getting no reachable servers

This is because [globalsign/mgo](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo) does not currently support SRV [connection string URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) yet. See [issues 112](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo/issues/112).
You can use the non-srv connection URI format (MongoDB v3.4), see a related question [StackOverflow: 41173720](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173720/connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-using-golang-mgo-persistent-no-reachable-server-to).

You can use [mongo-go-driver](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo) instead if you would like to connect using the SRV connection URI, for example:

```
mongoURI := "mongodb+srv://admin:password@prefix.mongodb.net/dbname?ssl=true&retryWrites=true"

client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURI))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second)
defer cancel()
err = client.Connect(ctx)
defer client.Disconnect(ctx)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
database := client.Database("go")
collection := database.Collection("atlas")
```

The above example is compatible with the current version v1.0.0

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it now I am getting a new error " cannot unmarshal DNS message". I checked online and I found that this was a bug that was already fixed long back. Is there anything I am missing here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which driver and which version are you using?

Comment: I used Mongodb 3.4 or below type of string connection and it works. As you told the new string style connections are still in dev. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: To clarify, the SRV string style is not in development however the `mongo-go-driver` version currently is.

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDB Atlas

```
 serverAPIOptions := options.ServerAPI(options.ServerAPIVersion1)
  clientOptions := options.Client().
    ApplyURI("mongodb://username:password@prefix0.mongodb.net:27017,prefix1.mongodb.net:27017,prefix2.mongodb.net:27017/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&replicaSet=atlas-zhqegh-shard-0&tls=true").
    SetServerAPIOptions(serverAPIOptions)
  ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
  defer cancel()
  client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
```

To clarify the MongoDB Atlas `replicaSet` and `hosts` you can for instance utilize `MongoDB Compass`: just connect to the cluster and you will see all that data.